# Import csv to mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I am using this code to import my data from csv to mongodb:

```
./mongoimport -d <db_name> -c <collection_name> --type csv --file <file_location/file.csv> --headerline
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failed: line 1, column 2446: extraneous " in field
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well without showing us your problematic CSV data it is difficult to give you a definitive answer but the error is usually caused when you have a CSV column wrapped in double quotes which contain a double quote within the wrapped text e.g.

```
C1,C2  
57,"This is a double quote:""
```

To solve the issue you have to escape the double quote with another one like so

```
C1,C2  
57,"This is a double quote:"""
```